# Topology, Proof of function being continuous

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $ (X_i,d_i),(Y_i,d_i^*)$, $i=1,\ldots,n $  be metric spaces. Let $ f_i:X_i \to Y_i, i=1,...,n $ be continuous functions. Let
>   $$ X = \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i , Y = \prod_{i=1}^{n} Y_i $$
>   and convert $X$ and $Y$ into metric spaces in the standard manner. Define the function $F:X \to Y $ by 
>   $$ F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = (f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots,f(x_n)). $$
>   Prove that $F$ is continuous.

The metric used to convert $X$ and $Y$ into metric spaces is $$ d(x,y) = \max\{d_i(x_i,y_i)\},\quad i=1,\ldots,n. $$

Proof: Let $\varepsilon_i \gt 0 $ be given. Since each $f_i$ is continuous, then $ \exists \delta_i \gt 0 $ such that if $$ d_i(x_i,y_i)\lt \delta_i \Rightarrow d_i^*(f_i(x_i),f_i(y_i))\lt \varepsilon_i. $$
For $1 \le i \le n.$ Now for $x,y \in X,$ if $$d(x,y) = \max\{d_i(x_i,y_i)\} = d_j(x_j,y_j)\le \delta_j $$then $ \exists \varepsilon_j $ such that 
$$ d(F(x),F(y)) = \max\{d_i^*(f_i(x_i),f_i(y_i)\} = d_j^*(x_j,y_j) \lt \varepsilon_j.$$
For some $1 \le j \le n.$ Therefore $F$ is continuous.

My main concern with my proof is whether different $\delta's$ and $\epsilon's$ are needed for this proof and if it is possible to find one such $\delta$ that would give me continuity of $F$?
I'm used to first doing scratch work and finding a single $\delta$, but for this problem I think continuity of each $f_i$ ensures $F$ is continuous.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think: Let $\varepsilon$ and not $\varepsilon_i$.

Comment: And after that choose $\delta=\min\delta_i$.

Comment: try to avoid using $y$ as an element in $X$, because that leads to think it is in $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $F(x)$ is continuous at $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_n)$, we need to show that for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, such that $d(x, x') < \delta$ implies $d^*(F(x), F(x')) < \epsilon$.

$d(F(x), F(x')) < \epsilon$ is equivalent to $d^*_i(f(x_i), f(x_i')) < \epsilon, \forall i$.

For each $i$, we can find $\delta_i >0$ such that $d_i(x_i, x_i') < \delta_i$ implies $d^*_i(f(x_i), f(x_i')) < \epsilon$. If we  take $\delta = \min\{\delta_i, i = 1,2,\cdots, n\}$, then $d(x, x') < \delta$ implies $d_i(x_i, x_i') < \delta_i, \forall i$.  Because $\max\{d_i(x_i, x_i'), i =1,\cdots, d\} = d(x, x') < \delta  = \min\{\delta_i, i = 1,2,\cdots, n\}$. The maximum of A is less than the minimum of B means all the elements in A are less than all the elements in B

So we used only one $\epsilon$, but different $\delta_i$'s

Comment: I'm finding it a bit difficult to see why the last implication holds, could you explain why its true?

Comment: @MiguelLanderos I added two lines to explain that

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the max when thinking about it.